# cytoscape-qtip.js official demo example does not show tooltip; how to manage cytoscape qtip

Tags: jquery, cytoscape.js, qtip2, qtip, cytoscape

**The official demo example of cytoscape-qtip.js** 
available at https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip/blob/master/demo.html
does not show any tooltips like it should. This demo file does not seem to work correctly. I have tested various browsers, tested removing cache files etc.

Please could you kindly provide me an answer that contains a full html file that works. 
So instead of providing only a detail of the correct code syntax, **please kindly give me one fully operational html demo file example**.
Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

The demo works fine.  I just tested it on Firefox, Chrome, and Safari.

Make sure you download the whole repo, make sure you have an active, unfettered internet connection, and make sure you disable any problematic browser extensions.